# How to reference types from external C libraries (e.g. pygame) in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

I'm writing a game using the pygame library and I'm trying to speed it up using Cython. I have made some progress but now, main performance bottlenecks (based on the HTML annotation file) are related to the interaction with pygame methods like `surface.subsurface()` and `pygame.transform.scale()`. As a first step, I would like to declare my pygame surface variables with the appropriate C type. Following the [Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), I added:

```c
cdef extern from "src_c/include/_pygame.h":
    ctypedef struct pgSurfaceObject
```

For this to work, I downloaded and symlinked the pygame source code which includes the following in [_pygame.h](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/54fcf0551a99ee71b64e0296531c3b4a1da15a82/src_c/include/_pygame.h#L486):

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD struct SDL_Surface *surf;
    int owner;
    struct pgSubSurface_Data *subsurface; /* ptr to subsurface data (if a
                                           * subsurface)*/
    PyObject *weakreflist;
    PyObject *locklist;
    PyObject *dependency;
} pgSurfaceObject;
```

When compiling my Cython module (called `raycasting.pyx`), I get the following output:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling raycasting.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing raycasting.pyx
running build_ext
building 'raycasting' extension
gcc -pthread -B /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/pygame/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/pygame/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/pygame/include -fPIC -I/home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/pygame/include/python3.11 -c raycasting.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/raycasting.o
In file included from raycasting.c:767:0:
src_c/include/_pygame.h:385:19: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_Rect’
     PyObject_HEAD SDL_Rect r;
                   ^~~~~~~~
src_c/include/_pygame.h:412:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_Joystick’
     SDL_Joystick *joy;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src_c/include/_pygame.h:450:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_PixelFormat’
     SDL_PixelFormat *vfmt;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src_c/include/_pygame.h:451:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_PixelFormat’
     SDL_PixelFormat vfmt_data;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Do I have to add SDL as a dependency? I just want to tell Cython about the type which is presumably available through the compiled pygame package (which I have installed via Conda). Is there an easier way to reference the header files, like via my `setup.py`?

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import Cython.Compiler.Options
Cython.Compiler.Options.annotate = True

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        'raycasting.pyx', annotate=True, language_level=3),
)
```

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to have the SDL headers available, since the `_pygame.h` header refers to them.

Comment: @AKX so I basically have to replicate the dependencies of the code I'm trying to use? I'm surprised I haven't found anyone else trying to do this rather simple thing. Are you perhaps aware of a real world example using some external library?

Comment: Since you're using Miniconda, you can probably just do `conda install -c conda-forge sdl2`.

Comment: I do have the `SDL.h` installed from Conda but how can I reference that in the code?

Comment: Probably just cdef extern from "SDL.h": pass?

Comment: That worked, along with using a `# distutils: include_dirs = /path/to/SDL` comment. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to use the type for assignment (`Cannot convert Python object to 'pgSurfaceObject'`) but perhaps that's a separate issue.

Comment: @AKX do you want to add an answer for that? Otherwise I will post one

Comment: Feel free to write it up as an answer yourself. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per user @AKX' suggestion, I did explicitly reference the SDL header in my `raycasting.pyx`:

```py
cdef extern from "SDL.h":
    pass
```

and to tell distutils about its location, I added the following comment on top of the file:

```py
# distutils: include_dirs = /path/to/SDL
```

I had to put the full path in it since using a variable like `$CONDA_PREFIX` didn't work, even though the header is located in my Conda environment.

This finally allowed me to use `pgSurfaceObject` as a Cython variable type.